# Rails float column converts letters to numbers automagically before my validations can take place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, type-conversion

I have a float column in the database of my rails project that saves a percentage from a form as a float.  When a user types in some combinations of letters and numbers such as "12jkawd3%"  it gets converted into a float before my validations can rule it out as invalid (it becomes a valid float).  I am currently using a method with a regex in the controller to prevent this from happening and it works but I feel like there must be a more rails way to do it.  I have consulted the googles and found nothing.  Can anyone help?

this is my controller currently.  The string_to_float method is what is keeping it from converting it into a float currently if invalid data is entered

```
class MyProductsNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    my_product = MyProduct.find(params[:my_product])
    discount = NumberFormatter.string_to_float(params[:my_products_notification][:discount])
    @my_products_notification = MyProductsNotification.new(my_product: my_product, discount: discount)
    if @my_products_notification.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      redirect_to current_user, notice: 'Invalid format for discount'
    end
  end
end
```

the NumberFormatter class(note ignore the else 0 as it is something for an edge case for the views.

```
class NumberFormatter
  class << self
   def string_to_float(discount_string)
      if discount_string =~ /(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$| )/
        discount_string
      else
        0
      end
    end
```

my model

```
class MyProductsNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_product
  before_create :string_to_float
  validates :discount, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100, message: 'is invalid.' }


  private
  def string_to_float
    self.discount = '%.2f' % (self.discount || 0)
  end
end
```

and the form:

```
<%= form_for @my_product_notification do |f| %>
        <% if product.my_products_notification %>
          <% discount = product.my_products_notification.discount %>
        <% else %>
          <% discount = '' %>
        <% end %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :my_product, product.id -%>
        <%= f.label "Percentage discount threshold: %"  %>
        <%= f.text_field :discount, value: discount %>
        <%= f.submit 'Save notification' %>
      <% end -%>
```

Comment: add reference code to your question

Answer (score 1):

Basically rails transform input data according to data type of your database column when ever you enter some value in variable. One way is that you use [attr_accessor](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor)

You can set value to attr_accessor and check validation on this variable and then update your old database float variable accordingly.

Comment: Where would the attr_accessor go?  Sorry I am a bit new to this.  Can you perhaps give me an example?

Comment: Attr_accessor does not store in database